# Очередь отложенных сообщений

Tags: php, rabbitmq, scheduler

Появилась задача, сделать демона, который будет выполнять задачи по расписанию. Сначала я думал все эти задачи сохранять в таблицу и демон чтобы их выполнял как время подходит. Но также нужно некоторые задания выполнять моментально. Я подумал сделать это через очередь сообщений RabbitMq. Но сейчас почитал и понял, что через Rabbit нельзя делать отложенные сообщения.

Возможно ли это реализовать только лишь через очередь сообщений и без костылей? (может что то кроме Rabbit есть). Или всё-таки делать два сервиса: мгновенные задачи и задачи по расписанию (через БД). Очень хотелось бы обойтись только MQ. Может есть какие-то еще идеи.

Comment: RabbitMQ - это не планировщик задач, и система доставки сообщений. Лучше будет использовать её по назначению, а crontab, либо sched для планировки. Есть также Gearman непосредственно для очередей различных задач, но он немного более гибкий - там можно использовать скрипты для проверки задач в очереди И время чтобы эту(и) задачи запускать.

Comment: Вполне можно сделать и в одном сервисе. rabbit будет отвечать за моментальные задачи, БД за отложенные. На очередном шаге чтения из БД вычисляете сколько времени до следующей запланированной задачи и делаете recv из раббита с таймаутом, равным этому времени.

Comment: @Mike Но получается нужно уже два демона, да? Тот который обрабатывает rabbit и тот, который будет чекать бд и отправлять из него в rabbit сообщения?

Comment: я предполагал что один демон работает и с БД и слушает раббит на случай, если его захотят известить о внеочередном задании. вопрос в том, для чего вы планировали использовать раббит

Comment: @Mike для начала, чтобы отправлять пуш уведомления, как отложенные так и моментально. И потом будет еще что-нибудь придумывать, чтобы не вис основной поток. Но главная цель конечно scheduler отложенных задач очень много уже. Мне ваша идея нравится, в конечном итоге всё делает один сервис, но честно говоря я не очень понял как с бд работать и с rabbit одновременно. Но не проблема чекать бд и отдельным демоном или вообще по крону.

Comment: А в каком случае у вас поток "зависает" ? Я вижу 2 причины: слишком долго выполняемое задание из очереди, но его можно выносить в другой поток. Или  происходит ожидание событий из раббита. Не знаю как в вашей библиотеке, но думаю у функции recv раббита должен быть таймаут на ожидание. Так вот этот таймаут устанавливается на время, которое осталось до следующего события, согласно расписанию в БД. Если в раббит за это время ничего не поступит, то recv все равно завершиться ровно в то время, когда будет работа

Comment: @Mike я имел ввиду если делать без Rabbit то зависает отдача ответа пользователю. Это же php, поэтому я не хочу в потоке где пользователь ждет html делать запрос к пушам (он может и зависнуть на пару секунд, а пользователю никакого ответа от этой операции не надо, вот я и решил сделать для этого отдельный сервис). Посмотрю recv, если действительно можно через него отложенную задачу сделать - хорошо, но что то везде пишут, что только обходными путями. Тогда и БД не нужна будет, он же бэкапит память.

Comment: Ну на чистом раббите отложенные делаются, но да, жесткими обходными путями. задача ставиться в очередь у которой x-message-ttl с нужной задержкой и установлен x-dead-letter-exchange, что бы по истечении ttl задачу перебрасывало в указанный ексчендж. Держать разные очереди под разные задержки такое себе решение. Мне все это то же не нравиться.